# Batch code processing on Applications different windows

Tags: windows, batch-file

Am not sure if this is possible but what am looking for is a code that can tell if a Windows desktop has finished loading preloader and has opened the main window, or in other words, is there a way I could get which window is currently displaying, if I could like get the windows name or something, I don't care which language is possible, if it's possible in any language not necessarily batch. thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
It's dawning on me that this might not be the right stack exchange site for this question, sorry about that but any help will still be appreciated. Will also ask on the right site

Comment: your question is unclear

Comment: I think you're looking for code to determine the current active window. Is that correct?

Comment: @SomethingDark yea but for a specific application

Comment: @GerhardBarnard where do you need clarification in, am ready to explain

Comment: The program has an initial preloader and once that's done loading a second window opens? And you're trying to check to see if that second window is open?

Comment: yea exactly @SomethingDark

Comment: Does that second window show up as its own process in the task manager?

Comment: the program is a software built by someone else, so am not sure if its a different process but i think it must be because after the preloader, next comes a login window @SomethingDark

Comment: Open the task manager and then open the program. I need to know if the new window appears as a different process because if it does, then you can check the output of `tasklist` in an infinite loop until it appears. If it doesn't, you can't use batch to do what you want.

Comment: tried monitoring it and i think its the same process, the next option i think maybe is getting the size of the window using the batch script, can i get the size of window of a particular process @SomethingDark

Comment: the title changes btw, i think that is the best option if i can get the title of the window, i can work with that, thanks. @SomethingDark

Comment: i got it, am using this `tasklist /fi "imagename eq process.exe" /fo list /v` now all I have to do is string manipulation to get the title of the window because the title changes so now I will use that infinite loop @SomethingDark

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to see if a window is running?

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq myapp.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "myapp.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" echo Program is running
```

replace `myapp.exe` with your aplication name.

If you are trying to find the title of a program that is running use

```
tasklist /fi "imagename eq myapp.exe" /fo list /v
```

all together that could be something like

```
@echo off
set app=myapp.exe

tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %app%" 2>NUL | find /I /N %app%">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" goto running
echo it is not running.

:running
tasklist /fi "imagename eq %app%" /fo list /v
pause
```